# How to make one option active and disable the others

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm creating a navbar.  when i click one of the options , that option becomes active but when i click on the other option the previous option which was active remains there

SEE MY FIDDLE EXAMPLE : https://jsfiddle.net/bpmbu3th/

I just want to make the item active which is clicked

MY HTML

```
  <p id="parent1">i'm the parent</p>
  <p id="child1">i'm the first child</p>

  <p id="parent2">i'm the 2nd parent</p>
  <p id="child2">i'm the second children</p>
```

MY CSS

```
 #parent1{

   background-color:#000;
   color:#fff;
 }
 #child1{

  display:none;
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
 }
 #parent2{

  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
 }
 #child2{

 display:none;
 background-color:red;
 color:#fff;
 }
```

MY JQUERY

```
  (function(){

        var object = {

            dropdown1:$('#child1'),
            dropdown2:$('#child2'),

            dropdown1parent: function(){
                if(object.dropdown1.is(':hidden')){
                    object.dropdown1.fadeIn();
                }
                else{
                    object.dropdown1.fadeOut();
                }

            },

            dropdown2parent: function(){

                if(object.dropdown2.is(':hidden')){
                    object.dropdown2.fadeIn();
                }
                else
                {
                    object.dropdown2.fadeOut();
                }
            }   


        };

        $('#parent1').on('click', object.dropdown1parent);
        $('#parent2').on('click', object.dropdown2parent);


    })();
```

Comment: Do you want =====> https://jsfiddle.net/71cdo562/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use common class to get rid of repetitive code.

Here's an example

```js
$(function() {
  $('.parent').on('click', function() {
    var child = $(this).next('.child'); //Finds the next child
    //fade out others then handle current child
    $('.child').not(child).fadeOut(function() {
      child.fadeToggle();
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
.child {
    display:none;
    background-color:red;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="parent">i'm the parent</p>
<p class="child">i'm the first child</p>
<p class="parent">i'm the 2nd parent</p>
<p class="child">i'm the second children</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add two lines of code in your javascript, here is the edited snippet -

```
dropdown1parent: function(){
                    if(object.dropdown1.is(':hidden')){
                        object.dropdown1.fadeIn();
                        object.dropdown2.fadeOut(); //this line
                    }
                    else{
                        object.dropdown1.fadeOut();
                    }

                },

                dropdown2parent: function(){

                    if(object.dropdown2.is(':hidden')){
                        object.dropdown1.fadeOut(); //this line
                        object.dropdown2.fadeIn();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        object.dropdown2.fadeOut();
                    }
                }
```

Is that you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

You need to fade out the other one:

```
(function () {

    var object = {

        dropdown1: $('#child1'),
        dropdown2: $('#child2'),

        dropdown1parent: function () {
            if (object.dropdown1.is(':hidden')) {
                object.dropdown1.fadeIn();
                object.dropdown2.fadeOut();
            } else {
                object.dropdown1.fadeOut();
                object.dropdown2.fadeOut();
            }

        },

        dropdown2parent: function () {

            if (object.dropdown2.is(':hidden')) {
                object.dropdown2.fadeIn();
                object.dropdown1.fadeOut();
            } else {
                object.dropdown1.fadeOut();
                object.dropdown2.fadeOut();
            }
        }


    };

    $('#parent1').on('click', object.dropdown1parent);
    $('#parent2').on('click', object.dropdown2parent);


})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/bpmbu3th/1/

You should think about creating a function to manage that, it will become a nightmare if you use a lot of "dropdown".